# How to Install Multiple Snaps Simultaneously?

Tags: snap

How do I install three Snap Apps at the same time? Let's pick these three

- Notes
- Shout
- Hangups

maybe

```
sudo snap install notes && sudo snap install shout && sudo snap install hangups
```

or

```
sudo snap install notes shout hangups
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second example you give works, on the proviso that all three use the same confinement model. If one of them requires the `--classic` confinement model, then it will need a separate install step.

So simply:-

```
snap install notes shout hangups
```

Will work. As you can see here:-

```
alan@hal:~$ snap install notes shout hangups
shout 0.53.0 from 'snapcrafters' installed
hangups 0.4.4 from 'tomdryer' installed
notes 0.9.0~gitb6e3b34 from 'notes-developers' installed
```

Answer (score 1):

**Parallel installs**

snap now also has an experimental parallel install feature documented at: https://snapcraft.io/docs/parallel-installs

As of snap 2.50.1 Ubuntu 21.04, if you do:

```
sudo snap install hello-world hello-world_foo
```

it fails with:

```
error: cannot install "hello-world", "hello-world_foo": experimental feature disabled - test it by
       setting 'experimental.parallel-instances' to true
```

and after:

```
sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true
```

the installation works.

However, if you run again:

```
sudo snap install hello-world hello-world_foo
```

it now fails with:

```
error: cannot install "hello-world", "hello-world_foo": no install/refresh information results from
       the store
```

and exits with status 1 which is annoying because I with it were idempotent by default while developing and re-running my setup scripts. This has been asked at: [Problem when trying to install multiple apps with snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232034/problem-when-trying-to-install-multiple-apps-with-snap)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible just specify wherever is needed

```
sudo snap install slack --classic && sudo snap install skype --classic && sudo snap install spotify htop
```

Hope to help! :)