# Problem when trying to install multiple apps with snap

Tags: software-installation, chromium, snap, 20.04, opera

I am trying to install multiple apps with one command using snap, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo snap install opera chromium
```

But I get the below error:

```
error: cannot install "opera", "chromium": no install/refresh information results from the store
```

Why do I get this error? I've found that if any app is using 'classic' confinement then separate commands are required. But both of those apps are on 'strict' confinement (this is what I see when I run `snap info chromium --verbose` and `snap info opera --verbose`.

Comment: I think this is a temporary problem and you should try again later.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduce minimally on snap 2.50.1 Ubuntu 21.04 as follows:

```
sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true
sudo snap install hello-world hello-world_foo
```

works for the initial installation, but if I re-run:

```
sudo snap install hello-world hello-world_foo
```

it outputs:

```
error: cannot install "hello-world", "hello-world_foo": no install/refresh information results from
       the store
```

and exits with status 1 which is annoying because I with it were idempotent by default while developing and re-running my setup scripts.

The initial `snap set` is needed otherwise the first command also fails as mentioned at: [Howto Install Multiple Snaps Simultaneously?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008731/howto-install-multiple-snaps-simultaneously/1344260#1344260)

This problem only happens if I run the command with two or more pre-installed packages, re-running:

```
sudo snap install hello-world
```

fails gracefully with status 0 as desired:

```
snap "hello-world" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

I asked about it on the forum at: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/trying-to-re-install-multiple-packages-with-snap-install-fails-with-install-refresh-information-results-from-the-store/24859

Answer (score 0):

Looks like server side problem

https://status.snapcraft.io/

27 Apr? «Snap downloads — Service Interruptions: 14:49 - 14:53».

Comment: well, just retried and same error. Services seem up and running now.